# How can I remove leading zeroes from PHP echo sql statements?

Tags: javascript, php, css, date, zero

I'm a front-end programmer on a 3-man team with very basic knowledge of PHP/MySQL, but our back-end programmer is going on vacation and we have a deadline to work on a small visual detail, so I'm trying to do it for him. As of right now, we are working on a page that shows several times for a variety of sessions occurring on a specific date. Below is what we currently have showing the times.

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($now['start'])) {
            echo $now['start'] .' - '. $now['end'];
    } ?>
```

This produces something like "01:30 pm - 02:30 pm" -- which would be perfect if it wasn't for the leading zeroes. The times themselves are provided by another group who is unable to remove the zeroes in the database themselves for whatever reason. Is there a way to make sure leading zeroes are concatenated in the same PHP statement?

If there's a solution for this in CSS or JavaScript I'd be open to hearing it as well, as those languages are more up my alley.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ltrim($now['start'], '0')`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... could I have the syntax wrong?

   `<?php 
  if(!empty($now['start'])) {
    echo ltrim($now['start'] .' - '. $now['end'], '0');
  }
    ?>`

Comment: You have to `ltrim` each of the `'start'` and `'end'` values, not the entire string. So `ltrim($now['start'], '0') . ' - ' . ltrim($now['end'], '0');`. `ltrim` removes the characters in the second argument from the left side of a string. If  you `ltrim` the whole string, it will remove the first zero but not the second because on the whole string, there is only one zero on the left side.

Answer (score 4):

Try ltrim

```
echo ltrim($string,"0");
```

and read about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

```
<?php

  $now = array( "start" => "01:30 pm", "end"=> "02:30 pm");

  if(!empty($now['start'])) {
    echo  ltrim($now['start'],"0") .' - '. ltrim($now['end'],"0");
  }

?>
```

which outputs

### 1:30 pm - 2:30 pm

and try it here http://3v4l.org/TkLKH

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working either... not getting any parse errors with this, but when I include this in the code it's not showing any difference on the times:
`<?php 
  if(!empty($now['start'])) {
    echo ltrim($now['start'] .' - '. $now['end'],"0");
  }
    ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It still doesn't work though, since it's pulling the data from a database... I can't define arrays since the times will cycle based on the current time/date. When I try this for other rooms it assumes the time/date is 1:30-2:30 for all, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

ltrim will be the easist solution, but a more flexible solution would be php's date function as it will allow you to output it in any format you like, including removing or changing the AM/PM or the format completely.

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($now['start'])) {
            echo date("g:i",strtotime($now['start'])) .' - '. date("g:i a",strtotime($now['end']));
    } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer, but I'm getting several parse errors from this (beginning with the ending ";" -- any idea why?

Comment: I was missing brackets, I have added them in.